# ¿Cómo puedo reutilizar este método?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, clase, método

Tengo una clase que esta heredando de otra:

```
class business2(business):
  steps()
```

La clase **business** tiene un método del cual quiero heredar todo ese procedimiento para no volver a escribir lo mismo.

```
def steps(self):
    i = 0
    while i < self.quantityY:
        years = int(input("year :"))
        sales = int(input(str(years)
            +" sales value :"))
        #we create a list without discount
        self.allyears.append(years)
        self.witOdiscounts.append(sales)

        i+=1
        if i == self.quantityY:
            for x in self.witOdiscounts:
                print(x)
```

Al ejecutar obtengo esto:

```
steps()
NameError: name 'steps' is not defined
```

La instancia por supuesto:

```
from exercise6 import *

instance = business2(2)
instance.steps()
```

Lo que quiero es reutilizar ese método para agregarle más cosas y no tener que copiarlo y pegarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a llamar a método manualmente de la forma:

```
instance.steps()
```

el intento de llamada en la clase hija con:

```
class business2(business):
    steps()
    #^^^^^#
```

sobra.

Cuando heredes de la clase padre, el método se hereda sin más, es exactamente como si lo hubieras definido en tu clase hija y se accede a él de forma idéntica:

```
class Business:

    def steps(self):
        i = 0
        while i < self.quantityY:
            years = int(input("year :"))
            sales = int(input(str(years)
                +" sales value :"))
            #we create a list without discount
            self.allyears.append(years)
            self.witOdiscounts.append(sales)

            i+=1
            if i == self.quantityY:
                for x in self.witOdiscounts:
                    print(x)

class Business2(Business):
    pass

instance = Business2(2)
instance.steps()
```

Si los quieres llamar de forma automática cundo se instancia la clase debes hacerlo desde el inicializador y usar `self.steps` para referenciarlo:

```
class Business2(Business):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.steps()

instance = Business2(2)
```

Si haces ésto:

```
class Business2(Business):
    self.steps()
```

el método se ejecutará en tiempo de definición no cuando instancias la clase.

En el caso que quieras sobrescribir el método en tu clase hija pero necesites que la ejecución del método del padre se lleve a cabo usa `super` para llamarlo:

```
class Business2(Business):
    def steps(self):
        super().steps()
        print("Ahora estoy ejecutando la parte propia de la clase hija")

instance = Business2(2)
instance.steps()
```

Como nota, recuerda que por convención las clases se nombran siempre usando CamelCase para diferenciarlas de módulos, funciones, métodos y variables que usan minúsculas y `_` como separador de palabras.

Comment: excelente respuesta muy amable FJSevilla